# Java Web Servlet update

Tags: java, xml, spring, tomcat

I have an application that is using the 2.3 Servlet and I need to update it, to use the 3.0 Servlet.
When I update the `<web-app>` tag, to match the new Servlet, I get the following errors:

> org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component
>   [StandardServer[8005]] Caused by:
>   org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component
>   [StandardService[Catalina]] Caused by:
>   org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component
>   [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]] Caused by:
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassFormatException: null is
>   not a Java .class file

My web.xml header looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee                       
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">"
```

Can anyone tell me what I am missing ?

Comment: what is the name and version of your server?

Comment: Are you sure that your `web.xml` passes validation against `web-app_3_0.xsd`? a few things were changed between 2.3 and 3.0; it's possible that your `web.xml` doesn't validate anymore, and with Tomcat making assumptions, it eventually blows up. Changing the `web-app` header may not be enough in your case.

Comment: I am using Tomcat 7.0 . I am not sure it passes validation, for what else should i be looking when updating the servlet ?